# Algorithm : concatenate sub-string based on their first and last characters

Tags: algorithm

Numbers of strings are given,

We need to join all strings to make single **valid string**.

All the characters of string are lowercase letters **[a-z]**.

**Valid string means :**

- We need to concatenate sub-string where the last letter of a sub-string match the first one of another one (example aa ab => becomes aaab // aa ba => becomes baaa)
- All the same characters of the string should be adjacent.

Calculate how many numbers of combinations are possible to make valid string.

**Example**:

input :

```
array(aa, ab, bc, aa)
```

desired output :

```
This expression got two possible combinaison.
(since "aa aa ab bc" is deferent from "aa aa ab bc", cause there is two aa, and they must not be considered equals)
```

**My efforts** :-

I just know its a graph problem. (Connected component Problem).

Please help me so that I can build this algorithm.

**I need your guidance, not exact algorithm. So that I can myself build the algorithm**

Comment: How second case resulted in `4`? For me, there's `0` because all pieces can not be combined with declared rules

Comment: Why is :
1. 1 solution and 
2. 4 solution? I got it, order matters

Comment: Why can't you make a string validator function, generate all possible string and filter out invalid ones?

Comment: There is a better and faster solution

Comment: @AlmaDo THere are 4 cases. Here order matters of all the strings.
Here there are two aa. Both are different. 4 cases are as :- aaaabcc, aaaabcc, bccaaaa, bccaaaa.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I will try to implement code after reading your answer, and will give you upvote. Give me one day time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How i'd handle this one :

Let's declare 2 variables :

```
int factorials_quotient = 1;
int solution_count = 0;
```

As an example, il will use string : `abc cme eqk aa a bb b`, since it it the trickiest case

> FIRST :  identify the '**concat**' strings.

Exemple : `abc cme eqk aa a bb b`

Since '`abc cme eqk`' string only have a unique order, you MUST concatenate them and consider it as a unique string : `abccmeeqk aa a bb b`. (For each concatenation, if the first letter equals the last letter on the substring, you got a exeption case, you must handdle it).

> SECOND:  identify the '**factorials**' strings.

Exemple : `abccmeeqk aa a bb b`
We are looking for two or more string containing the same characters like : `aa a` & `bb b` (DO NOT count 'abcmeeqk' since it contains char different from a).

For each of these string multiply `factorials_quotient` by n!

In our case, we first got `aa a`, since we have 2 string (a and aa) we multiply `factorials_quotient` by factorial(2), then the same for `bb b`. our `factorials_quotient` now equals 1 * 2! * 2! = 4.

Then concatenate `aa` to `a` and `bb` to `b`.

We now got : `abccmeeqk aaa bbb`.

> THIRD : try to concatenante the **factorials** and the **concats** if it is possible.

Exemple we not have `abccmeeqk aaa bbb`.

Since `abccmeeqk` start with `a` qe have to put `aaa` in  front of, we now got : `aaaabccmeeqk bbb`

> FOUR : get your result

`solution_cuount = factorials_quotient * factorial(number of sub-string in our string)`

In our case : `aaaabccmeeqk bbb` we got 2 sub-string.

`solution_count = 4 * 2! = 4 * 2`= 8 solutions :

Possible solutions :

```
aa  a   abc cme eqk bb  b
aa  a   abc cme eqk b   bb
a   aa  abc cme eqk bb  b
a   aa  abc cme eqk b   bb

bb  b   aa  a   abc cme eqk
b   bb  aa  a   abc cme eqk
bb  b   a   aa  abc cme eqk
b   bb  a   aa  abc cme eqk
```

Array step by step :

**STEP 0: (at start)**

```
array(
    "aa",
    "a",
    "abc",
    "cme",
    "eqk",
    "bb",
    "b"
)
```

**STEP 1:**

```
array(
    "aa",
    "a",
    "abccmeeqk",
    "bb",
    "b"
)
```

**STEP 2:**

```
array(
    "aaa",
    "abccmeeqk",
    "bbb"
)
```

**STEP 3:**

```
array(
    "aaaabccmeeqk",
    "bbb"
)
```

**STEP 4:**

```
you got your result
```

Comment: How would you handle a situation like `["aa", "ab", "ca", "aa"]`? Also, you forgot the case where the answer is 0, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @NiklasB. I just wrote a method to solve this, this particular case is pretty tricky and must be handled as a particular one while writing the code. As he said `I need your guidance, not exact algorithm`.
What do you by case where answer is 0?

Comment: i just correct a mistakes on result calculation.

Comment: E.g. `["ab", "bc", "ca"]`.

Comment: Well i kind of forget this one, answer is not 0, answer is 2

Comment: no, there is no solution

Comment: `ab bc ca` & ``ca ab bc` there is 2, letters does not have to be alphabetically sorted

Comment: abbcca is not a valid string according to OP's definition, and neither is caabbc

Comment: @NiklasB. added a warn, it's up to the OP to handle this exception while writing the code. thanks for the feedback ;)

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Thanks for your nice answer. I understand the basic fundaa behind this. Can you tell me complexity of your steps in algorithm ?

Comment: @devnull i'm sorry but i'm not english native speaker, i did not understood you, what do you mean by  "tell complexity of your step in algorithm"

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond What is the TIME COMPLEXITY, means how much it will take to run your algorithm ?

Comment: @devnull i have absolutely no idea,  plus it depends how you handle the first step wich is imo the longuest